# CMake target_include_directory doesn't provide include

Tags: cmake

I have the small project that looks like shown below:

```
/
 CMakeLists.txt
 src/
     CMakeLists.txt
     sources...
 libs/
      foo/
          CMakeLists.txt
          src/
              sources...
          include/
                  headers...
```

The CMakeLists.txt files look like this:

/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
add_subdirectory(libs/foo)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(my_app
        main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(my_app ${MY_LIB})
```

/libs/foo/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)    
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(MY_LIB httpOnThreads)
set(MY_LIB_INCLUDE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(${MY_LIB} STATIC
        include/foo.h src/foo.cpp
)

target_include_directories (${MY_LIB} PUBLIC
        ${MY_LIB_INCLUDE} )
target_include_directories(${MY_LIB} PRIVATE src)
```

I expect `target_link_libraries(my_app ${MY_LIB})` will be provide include information. But, when I try to build the project, I have fatal error: `No such file or directory`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: `${HTTP_ON_THREADS_INCLUDE} `? You sure it's not `${MY_LIB_INCLUDE}`?

Comment: @Kamiccolo, sorry, you right, it's typing mistake. But it still doesn't work, as I said above.

Comment: Please create a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Voting to close.

Comment: I forgot to add: a good way to debug this is to look at verbose commands being used for compile. On Make: `make VERBOSE=1`, Ninja: `ninja --verbose`. In your example, I found that there was not a single include for target `main.cpp.o`.

Comment: Prefer to use [`target_compile_features(${MY_LIB} PUBLIC "cxx_std_14")`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in `src/CMakeLists.txt` you have:

```
target_link_libraries(my_app ${MY_LIB})
```

However, in this scope, the variable `MY_LIB` is not defined and thus empty.

Replacing that line with

```
target_link_libraries(my_app httpOnThreads)
```

solves the issue.

I would recommend to be explicit on the library name.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Does it exist a way to forward variable from between CMakeLists?

Comment: @voltento: take a look at `PARENT_SCOPE` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html but as already mentioned by @Unapiedra, it's better to be explicit.